# Clean HTML output in ZF2

Tags: html, frameworks, zend-framework2, format, output

Is it possible to fomat(clean) output of html in Zend Framework 2? Right now it outputs without proper newline characters and tabs.

I know about this method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

But I do not understand where I could intercept output in ZF2. Any help would be appreciated.

Right now all the html code is created in layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to the "finish" mvc-event ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html ) and have it clean up the response before sending it out.

In your application's module.php add something like the following to the Module class.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{ 
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, function(MvcEvent $e){
        $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
        $cleancontent = clean_up_html(content); // clean_up_html() not provided
        $e->getResponse()->setContent($cleancontent);
    });
}
```